# change direction into random direction on collision Unity2D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to create a game where there's a ball that can move
in the direction by dragging and releasing on the screen and that change direction randomly when hitting a prefab,  I already created that kind of movement but couldn't figure out how to make the ball change direction randomly when hitting the prefab.
Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask.

Here's my script

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float power = 2;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 minPow, maxPow;
    public Vector3 force;
    private Vector3 startPoint, endPoint;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Camera cam;
    private Aim aim;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        aim = GetComponent<Aim>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startPoint.z = 15;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 currentPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startPoint.z = 15;
            aim.RenderLine(startPoint, currentPos);
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            endPoint.z = 15;

            force = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.x - endPoint.x, minPow.x, maxPow.x), Mathf.Clamp(startPoint.y - endPoint.y, minPow.y, maxPow.y));
            rb.AddForce(force * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            aim.EndLine();
        }
    }
    public void BoostUp(float pow)
    {
        rb.velocity *= pow;
    }
}



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Boost : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float pow;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Player player = other.GetComponent<Player>();
            if(player != null)
            {
                player.BoostUp(pow);
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random angle in radians using `Random.Range(0f, 2f * Mathf.PI)` and then pass it to *Mathf.Cos* and *Mathf.Sin* functions to get a direction with that angle:

```
float angle = Random.Range( 0f, 2f * Mathf.PI );
Vector2 direction = new Vector2( Mathf.Cos( angle ), Mathf.Sin( angle ) );
```